# How do I backup wallet for first time

Tags: wallet, backup

I tried to send Crypto to my brand new digital wallet.  I was informed I must backup wallet first.  How do I back up my digital wallet for first use?

Comment: The method can depend on which wallet you use. Are you using Bitcoin-core, Electrum, Bread or something else? Are you using an account with a web based service? If so which?

Answer (score 1):

Just write down the 12 words and put them back in and its done.  never give out them words because that your passphrase or in other words your Backup